# Break on Exceptions - Exclude List

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm a big fan of the Break on Exceptions setting in VS2010, and use it quite a lot. However I'm slowly finding that the number of exceptions I have to exclude for one reason or another is increasing. Currently I've got 4 that I need to ignore most of the time.

The thing if, it's quite an overhead to go search for these and disable them after turning everything on. Does anyone know if there's a way to enable all but a default set?